# How to resolve/replace library used in Espresso tests 'Unresolved reference: common'

Tags: android-espresso

I have inherited an Espresso test project. The app builds, but the AndroidTest fails with this error, "Unresolved reference: common".

It is importing a library 'com.google.common.truth.Truth'. Apparently this used to work, but doesn't any longer.

I understand that this is a an assert library, but I can't figure out how to get the errors to resolve.

I added this to my build.gradle file and it has done nothing but add more errors.

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.4"
}
```

Can someone please explain how to fix this? I'm new to Espresso, but have done other UI Automation. This is making me crazy.

I added this to my build.gradle file and it has done nothing but add more errors.

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.4"
}
```